# How can Named Dispatch be tested without publishing to marketplace?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am developing a capsule and want to test if it works as desired with Named Dispatch.

However, I am unable to trigger the default action in Simulator or as a private capsule on my device.
**Instead of the default-action, another action (that does have Training entries) is invoked.**

The problem seems to be, that **before testing, the capsule has to be set. Therefore, named dispatch is circumvented.**

How can Named Dispatch (as described here https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/capsule-info.dispatch-name#how-named-dispatch-works) be tested **without publishing to the marketplace**?

#### Current configuration

- default-action (MyDefaultAction) is set appropriately in capsule.bxb.
- There are no Training entries for the default-action.
- I am using the commands from this list: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/ref-topics/meta-commands.de-de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the [seven reserve utterance](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/ref-topics/meta-commands.en-us) to test in IDE simulator:

"speak to %dispatch-name%"

"talk to %dispatch-name%”

"start %dispatch-name%"

"load %dispatch-name%"

"ask %dispatch-name%"

"talk with %dispatch-name%”

"use %dispatch-name%"

Remember that it is only valid for en-US target. 
You can check out Github example and more details in this [KB article](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040053614).

Comment: Does the restriction on en-US target apply only to **testing**? I.e.: Will named dispatch work for actual users when a capsule is published to the marketplace with only de-DE target?

Comment: Not just IDE, it is enforced at platform level, meaning restriction also apply to marketplace.

Comment: I see. If default-action is not available in e.g. **de-DE target**, what is the best practice approach to implement a use case similar to this one? :

-> User invokes a capsule that plays radio stations and specifies which station they want to hear: "*Ask MyRadioCapsule to play RadioStationXYZ*". 
A 3rd party webservice provides search results and stores users station preference.
The next time, the user just says "*Bixby, open MyRadioCapsule*", the last played station is fetched from the webservice and played.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to use "start/open MyRadioCapsule" in target other than en-US at the moment.